# How do you store these generic parameters?

Tags: c#, generics

I am working with ServiceStack. This library has a method for dependency injection, called Register.

```
public IRegistration<TService> Register<TService>(TService> instance)
```

Which you call like this:

```
Container.Register<IFirstServiceInterface>(new FirstServiceInterfaceImplementation());
Container.Register<ISecondServiceInterface>(new SecondServiceInterfaceImplementation());
```

Now, I want to create a method which takes the same parameters as Register. In my method however, I would add the passed instance and interface type to an ICollection object, to pass it to ServiceStack's Register method at a later point in time. At the time I want to pass these parameters to ServiceStack, I would simply call:

```
foreach(var item in dependencyCollection)
{
    ServiceStack.Register(item); 
    //not exactly how you call the Register method, but you get the idea. 
}
```

How would I set up a collection object to achieve the result I'm looking for? I'm having trouble storing both an interface type, and an implementation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to infer what you're looking for here, but maybe you're looking at some of ServiceStack Funq's IOC late-bound API's? e.g:

```
container.Register(
    new FirstServiceInterfaceImplementation(), 
    typeof(IFirstServiceInterface));

//or
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(
    typeof(FirstServiceInterfaceImplementation),
    typeof(IFirstServiceInterface));
```

In which to use the first API you can use a `Dictionary<Type,object>`, e.g:

```
var deps = new Dictionary<Type,object> {
    { typeof(IFirstServiceInterface), new FirstServiceInterfaceImplementation() },
    { typeof(ISecondServiceInterface), new SecondServiceInterfaceImplementation() },
};
```

Then register like:

```
foreach (var entry in deps) 
{
    container.Register(entry.Value, entry.Key);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! The problem was that I did not know this overload exists.